# How may I check if my app has access to phone gallery

Tags: ios, uiimage, gallery

I have an app in which I take a picture with the camera and store that image into the native gallery. But if the app doesn't have permission for that, I want the user to know that. So how do I check it?

By the way: I store the image into the gallery with:

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
```

Comment: can we change the answer to the correct one, or put version info into the question?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to check the status of `ALAssetLibrary` 
make sure you have `AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h` included in your file

```
  ALAuthorizationStatus status = [ALAssetsLibrary authorizationStatus];
```

// check the status for `ALAuthorizationStatusAuthorized` or `ALAuthorizationStatusDenied` e.g

```
    if (status != ALAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
        //show alert for asking the user to give permission

    }
```

Comment: it should work on ios5+ , if you see ALAssetLibrary then you would notice that it has support for ios5+

Comment: for further reference you could use [ALAssetLibrary Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: well i added AssetsLibrarz.framework but when i do import "ALAssetLibrary.h" i get error that it can not be found

Comment: Include it like #import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>

Answer (score 5):

Swift 3

```
import photos

PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { status in
     switch status {
     case .authorized:
          self.processSnapShotPhotos()
     case .restricted:
          print("handle restricted")
     case .denied:
          print("handle denied")     
     default:
       // place for .notDetermined - in this callback status is already determined so should never get here
            break
     }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using photos framework since ALAsset libraries are deprecated from ios 9 you can use PHAuthorizationStatus to check gallery access. You need to import photos framework as well.

```
  #import <Photos/Photos.h>

- (BOOL)hasGalleryPermission
{
    BOOL hasGalleryPermission = NO;
    PHAuthorizationStatus authorizationStatus = [PHPhotoLibrary authorizationStatus];

    if (authorizationStatus == PHAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
        hasGalleryPermission = YES;
    }
    return hasGalleryPermission;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Note: iOS 6 Only

Is this what you are looking for

```
[ALAssetsLibrary authorizationStatus] == ALAuthorizationStatusAuthorized;
```

Other values of authorizationStatus are

```
ALAuthorizationStatusRestricted,        // This application is not authorized to access photo data.
                                            // The user cannot change this application’s status, possibly due to active restrictions
                                            //  such as parental controls being in place.
    ALAuthorizationStatusDenied,            // User has explicitly denied this application access to photos data.
    ALAuthorizationStatusAuthorized         // User has authorized this application to access photos data.
```

Comment: why is this iOS6 only? I need for all joss, but that's what i need

Comment: authorizationStatus  method is available in iOS 6.0 and later.

Comment: So what am i supposed to do with earlier versions?

Comment: Check error in the completion block. Though an OS alert will pop up as soon as you call UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum asking user to grant permission.

Comment: Also on iOS 5 and lower you did not need permission to write to the phone gallery.

Comment: @gabrjan this does not answered your query or was not helpful ?

Comment: well i tested storring and i got no error when i didn't have permission just nothing happend.