# How can I get the authorization status to Photo/Camera on IOS?

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using `UIImagePickerController`. I need guide my user to `Setting -> Privacy` to unlock the camera/photo access if they rejected it in the first place.

By default, `UIImagePickerController` will show:

[image: without auth]

But how about i want the message before presenting `UIImagePickerController`? How can i get the message that whether i have the access?

**I want to claim that it is not an absolute duplicated question. `AVCaptureDevice` in this question [detect permission of camera on ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20464631/detect-permission-of-camera-on-ios) only fixes the access to the camera, but the access to 'photo album' still cannot be detected.**

Comment: possible duplicate of [detect permission of camera on ios](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20464631/detect-permission-of-camera-on-ios)

Comment: using `AVCaptureDevice` only fixes the access to the camera, not to the photo album. @Jeff

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the question [detect permission of camera on ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20464631/detect-permission-of-camera-on-ios) mentioned the class `AVCaptureDevice`, it can fix the authorization of `Camera Usage`.

I found the solution to the authorization of 'photo'. There is a new framework called `Photos` in IOS8 and a class `PHPhotoLibrary`.

This method can give an Alert:

```
PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({(status: PHAuthorizationStatus)in
    switch status{
    case .denied:
        break
    case .authorized:
        break
    default:
        break
    }
})
```

[image]

Just like when `UIImagePickerController` appears the first time.

and `class func authorizationStatus() -> PHAuthorizationStatus` can return the current authorization status of 'photo album'

Answer (score 4):

The AVCaptureDevice provides API for this.

```
        if (![[AVCaptureDevice  class] respondsToSelector:@selector(authorizationStatusForMediaType:)])
        {
            //Do something…
            break;
        }

        AVAuthorizationStatus authStatus = [AVCaptureDevice authorizationStatusForMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
        switch (authStatus)
        {
            case AVAuthorizationStatusAuthorized:
            case AVAuthorizationStatusRestricted:
            {
                //Do something…
                break;
            }
            case AVAuthorizationStatusDenied:
            {
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"App name" message:@"Appname does not have access to your camera. To enable access, go to iPhone Settings > AppName and turn on Camera." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alert show];

                //Do something…
                break;
            }
            case AVAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined:
            {
                // not determined?!
                [AVCaptureDevice requestAccessForMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo completionHandler:^(BOOL granted)
                 {
                     if(granted)
                     {
                         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
                         {
                             //Do something…
                         });
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
                         {
                             //Do something…
                         });
                     }
                 }];
                break;
            }
            default:
                break;
        }
```