# Read camera permission for iOS in Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, ios-camera

I have an iOS app developed in Xamarin. When the app does not have permission to access the microphone, if the user tries to access the microphone from the app, I check the settings using `AVAudioSession.SharedInstance().RequestRecordPermission (delegate(bool granted))` and display a message.

Now I need to do the same if the app does not have permission to access the camera. I need to check if permission is granted for camera and display a message accordingly. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you checked this answer? 
[Detect permission of camera in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20464631/detect-permission-of-camera-in-ios)
I think that's the solution you are looking for :).

EDIT:
Here is the highest voted answer's code ported to C#

```
// replace the media type to whatever you want
AVAuthorizationStatus authStatus = AVCaptureDevice.GetAuthorizationStatus(AVMediaType.Video);
switch (authStatus)
{
    case AVAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined:
        break;
    case AVAuthorizationStatus.Restricted:
        break;
    case AVAuthorizationStatus.Denied:
        break;
    case AVAuthorizationStatus.Authorized:
        break;
    default:
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
}
```

Comment: Thanx. Yes I have read this link. I wanted help in specific to Xamarin.

Answer (score 5):

I have got the answer. Here is what I have done:

```
AVCaptureDevice.RequestAccessForMediaType (AVMediaType.Video, (bool isAccessGranted) => {                    
   //if has access              
   if(isAccessGranted)
   {
      //do something
   }
   //if has no access
   else
   {
      //show an alert
   }
});
```