# Xamarin iOS app crashes when using RequestPermissionAsync to ask for camera permissions

Tags: ios, xamarin, permissions, enterprise

I am trying to get camera functionality to work in Xamarin.iOS on an iPad with an Enterprise account.

When I use an Enterprise account, the app crashes as soon as I ask for permission:

```
var status = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionAsync<CameraPermission>();
```

even though a message shows if I want to let the app use the camera.
When I say I want to use the camera and then open the app again, I CAN use the camera without issues.
I have set the Camera Usage Description in the Info.pList
(When I run the same line of code with a developer subscription on the same iPad, it does not crash the first time, and it does not ask for permission)

Is there anything I am missing?
Is there another solution I can use?

```
Xamarin.Forms           v4.8.0.1687
Xamarin.Essentials      1.6.0-pre3
Plugin.Permissions      6.0.1
iPad                    iOS13.2.3
```

I use VS2019 in Windows

Comment: have you tried to catch the exception causing the crash?  Is anything shown in the logs?

Comment: I have tried to catch the exception and didn't find anything in the logs.

Comment: @VincentvanRooijen Hi, do you have a try with using [xamarin essentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/permissions?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android#requesting-permissions) to ask the permission?

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT, yes, I have tried that too.  That also crashes.

Comment: @VincentvanRooijen Not using the preview version of xamarin essentials. And if you have other devices, can have a try.

Comment: @VincentvanRooijen And here is a native method to ask permission for camera, you also could have a try.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31177640/read-camera-permission-for-ios-in-xamarin

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT, so I use that in Xamarin.iOS and not in the general Xamarin code for all devices?

Comment: @VincentvanRooijen Generally, it should work for all devices. But here it not works, so you could have a try with native method to check whether it works. If it works, it should be an issue for the `xamarin essentials` and `Plugin.Permissions`, then can submit it in github.