# My Application does not have access to camera or videos in media in iOS 10 at very first time

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

got the below issue in my application..i got below issue iOS 10 only. before versions the issue is not replicated.

1) Install/Reinstall the  my iOS build.
2) Go to media items --> Images/video. 
3) While using "Take photo" and "Take Video" option at very first time, it will ask the 
permission to take the photo/video. Now confirm the permission.

Issue: Once the confirm the permission it should be in camera screen, but still it is in my application 
app screen.

I am adding  “Privacy - Camera Usage Description” in info.plist. but still getting same issue.

My Code:

```
AVAuthorizationStatus authStatus = [AVCaptureDevice authorizationStatusForMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

if (authStatus == AVAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) 

{

// do your logic

UIImagePickerController *imagePickController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];

if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) 

{
                    imagePickController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

imagePickController.delegate = self;

imagePickController.allowsEditing = NO;

imagePickController.showsCameraControls = YES;

[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock: ^{

[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden = YES;

[self presentViewController:imagePickController animated:YES completion:nil];

}];

}

else {

UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"CAMERA_NOTAVAILABLE", nil) message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:LOC(@"ok"), nil];

[alertView show];

[alertView setTag:Camera_Access_TAG];

}
```

Comment: As first time you must be checking granted. And if it's granted then you might be doing nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to check the permission before presenting camera:

```
func checkForCameraAccess() -> Bool{
    let authStatus = AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(forMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)
    switch authStatus {
    case .authorized: return true
    case .denied: return false
    case .notDetermined: return false
    default: return false
    }
}
```

This will solve the issue.

Comment: i am editing my question. please check it once.. and give me in objective c.. i have no idea in swift

Answer (score 0):

You might not doing anything at time of requesting permission. So write you code as below. To request permission

```
[AVCaptureDevice requestAccessForMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo completionHandler:^(BOOL granted)
             {
                 if(granted)
                 {
                     //Use your authorised code here
                 }

             }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if i am mistaken, your question seems different and your code saying different scenario.

If you want to get Media from Photo Library (As you have mentined in question)

**Privacy - Camera Usage Description**
- This permission will let user ask for permission to access device camera not photo library.

If you want to open photo library, you must include

**NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription**

Here is the link to all Information Property List Key Reference by Apple.
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html

and change your source to

- UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.savedPhotosAlbum
- UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary

**Or** If the question is just about accessing camera and it permission
Here is answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20464727

Comment: The problem is in ios 10. app install and try to access camera the above issue is getting @Dev_Tandel

Comment: see the link in answer to check for permission @Surya

Comment: This will help you to solve your permission issue, and it is in Obj C

Comment: You will be access photo Library same way as camera, you need to just change source type

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138499/discussion-between-surya-and-dev-tandel).

Answer (score 0):

For swift 3.0.1:

```
if PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus() == .authorized {
    print("authorized")

} else {
    print("Not authorized")
    AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(forMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) { response in
    if response {
        //access granted
        print("AV access")
    } else {
        print("AV Denied Permission")
    }
   }
}
```