# my iPhone app crashes and unable to restart on disabling camera access in Settings

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera, settings

It happens no matter I run it under release mode or debug mode. If it is due to the automatic shutdown by iOS, there should be a re-start. But my app is unable to do that. 
the output on the console:
Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 9

But I don't think disabling camera will cause a memory issue.
My Root.plist is like this:
[screenshot of plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9uA9.png)

However, if I choose "don't allow" at the popup when first launching, the app is running normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have code snippet? Or full error message?

Let me take a guess. In your code where you access the camera, you should check the camera permission before you just use it. I think that's where the problem would be. For how to do that, check [question]: [Detect permission of camera in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20464631/detect-permission-of-camera-in-ios) But I might be wrong. need more info. And I also think you didn't correctly set your plist, you need to add following attributes in you plist.

**Photo :**

```
Key: Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description    
Value: $(PRODUCT_NAME) photo use
```

**Microphone :**

```
Key: Privacy - Microphone Usage Description    
Value: $(PRODUCT_NAME) microphone use
```

**Camera :**

```
Key: Privacy - Camera Usage Description   
Value: $(PRODUCT_NAME) camera use
```

And one more thing, when you encounter a crash or any weird behavior, look for its reason, look into its log, look deeply into its err message. search for the error code, put `exception breakpoints` to find exactly where the crash happens, etc. And then, post questions related to how you cannot solve those materials/experiments you went through. That is more effective than just agonize yourself over the app behavior.

Comment: Thank you Elvin! Yes, the problem is with checking the camera access in code.

Comment: @Wanda glad it helped. Please choose this as accepted answer if it solves your problem. Thanks.